# Activity working fine in <=Android 4.1 but died in Android 4.2 (ActivityManager: process has died)

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm creating an application for reading online novel and it works in Android 2.3.3 - 4.1, but somehow in Android 4.2, one of the Activity (DisplayLightNovelContentActivity) is suddenly died when reading one of the chapter (Sword Art Online:Aria in the Starless Night, original page: http://baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Sword_Art_Online:Aria_in_the_Starless_Night)

This only happen in Android 4.2 (Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 7, Nexus 10), it is working ok in previous version of Android.

Based on the log file, I'm seeing a lot of process was died by ActivityManager before my application died (lnreader).

These are the log files: http://pastebin.com/fgXKG1Ew and http://pastebin.com/dQgEJmik

This is the source code: https://github.com/calvinaquino/LNReader-Android

Can someone explain to me? Any fundamental changes on how android 4.2 that affected my application?

Comment: are you getting Force Close?

Comment: i have tested your code. and it runs like charm on my nexus10 with android4.2 can you tell me on wich part you are finding error?

Comment: @Bhavesh: It is not FC, the activity just died. Also not all chapter will cause the problem. If you open chapter from Sword Art Online --> Side Stories --> Aria_in_the_Starless_Night and try to read/scroll, it will closed after few minutes. The log file only show `11-17 04:57:06.946: I/ActivityManager(476): Process com.erakk.lnreader (pid 18764) has died.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the cause. Removing the deprecated method `onPictureListener()` fixed the problem in Android 4.2.1.

Tested in Galaxy Nexus 4.2.1 and Nexus 10.

No replacement method/class given by Google, so I change the code to use javascript.